# How can I setup SSL for Kafka running in docker?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I would like to make the development environment of the application as similar as possible, therefore I would like to prepare all containers application interacts with. The problem is app interacts with Kafka, with the usage of SSL and SASL. I struggle to find a way how to set up such a Kafka broker locally via Docker.

server.properties

```
broker.id=1
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.rcovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-1:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.10-jre-buster

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl
         
ENV KAFKA_VERSION 2.7.0
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.13 

RUN  mkdir /tmp/kafka && \
    curl "https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz" \
    -o /tmp/kafka/kafka.tgz && \
    mkdir /kafka && cd /kafka && \
    tar -xvzf /tmp/kafka/kafka.tgz --strip 1

COPY start-kafka.sh  /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x  /usr/bin/start-kafka.sh

CMD ["start-kafka.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  zookeeper-1:
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    image: aimvector/zookeeper:2.7.0
    build:
      context: ./zookeeper
    volumes:
    - ./config/zookeeper-1/zookeeper.properties:/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
    - ./data/zookeeper-1/:/tmp/zookeeper/
    networks:
    - kafka
  
  kafka-1:
    container_name: kafka-1
    image: aimvector/kafka:2.7.0
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    build: 
      context: .
    volumes:
    - ./config/kafka-1/server.properties:/kafka/config/server.properties
    - ./data/kafka-1/:/tmp/kafka-logs/
    networks:
    - kafka

networks: 
  kafka:
    name: kafka
```

Comment: Ref: https://lff0305.medium.com/build-a-kafka-cluster-with-ssl-with-docker-docker-compose-and-java-client-5d54fa9cb290

Comment: Why don't you use existing Kafka images?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I could not make it work when I tried to use confluent or wurstmeister image.